# EventEmmitter: access the event from within the callback

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

Can I have access to the name of an event from within the callback which is executed when the event is triggered?

Consider the following example, where I have the same callback  (`handleEvent`)for two differenct events. Now I want to add a conditional statement in the callback based on the event that triggered its execution. Is this possible?

```
obj.on('start', handleEvent);
obj.on('stop', handleEvent);

function handleEvent() {
       // how can I check here if the event that triggers the execution of handleEvent is 'start' or 'stop'

}
```

What I do at the moment is to pass the event two times with 'emit' - which seems to be working fine, but i don't like to write it twice:

```
obj.emit('start', 'start', handleEvent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [EventEmitter2](https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2):

```
var EventEmitter = require('eventemitter2').EventEmitter2
var emitter = new EventEmitter

emitter.on('test', onEvent)
emitter.emit('test')

function onEvent() {
  console.log(this.event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
obj.on('start', handleEvent.bind({ event: 'start' }));
obj.on('stop', handleEvent.bind({ event: 'stop' }));

function handleEvent() {
    if(this.event == 'start') { ///
}
```